# Laravel 5.2 implicit route model binding using uuid string as id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm setting up a new laravel installation and have come to an issue with implicit route model binding when using a uuid as an id.

My route:

```
Route:group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function(){
    Route:resource('users', 'Admin\UserController');
});
```

The show method of Admin\UserController:

```
public function show(App\User $user) {
    dd($user);
}
```

So when I hit the URL `my.app/admin/users/long-uuid-string-here` I would expect to see the user information but I get an empty User object.

When I add the following to the RouteServiceProvider, it works as expected:

`$router->model('admin/users', \App\User::class);`

Is there something I am missing, does implicit model binding expect an integer? Is it because it is in a route group or something else?

**Yes!** the id exists in the database, and I am using laravel 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using resource routing, the route will be like:

`Route::get('admin/users/{users}', 'Admin\UserController@show');`

Note the `{users}` variable. It's plural. So in your show method:

change this:

```
public function show(App\User $user) {
    dd($user);
}
```

to

```
public function show(App\User $users) {
    dd($users);
}
```

It's a bit weird, but thats the problem.

Comment: I'm using the uuid in the id column

Comment: Where did you register your `$router->model()` method?

Comment: In the boot method of the RouteServiceProvider. It works if I explicitly declare it that way, I was wondering why it wasn't working implicitly. Following your reasoning, I guess it must be to do with the fact it's in a prefixed group?

Comment: @BenHarvey: Found the problem and posted the solution.

Comment: If you don't like plural notation in route names and parameters, you can add `Route::singularResourceParameters();` to your `routes.php`, and they will be singularized.